# Search for AoE cards in hearthstone

Tags: hearthstone

A lot of my decks lack AoE which is kind of their Achilles' Heel.  How do I scan my collection for AoE cards?

[image]

Comment: You can only search for text that is on the cards. Card types and text like "Beast" or "Dragon" or "All" or "Enemies" work. Keywords like "Deathrattle" or "Battlecry" also work. You can't search for things like "Alliance" to get all alliance based cards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that most AoE cards have either the phrase "**all enemies**" (if it will hit face) or "**all enemy minions**" (if it will only hit the minions).

As such, searching for the phrase "**all enem**" will bring up most of the AoE cards (and some non-AoE cards that deal random damage split among enemies).

Source: I just logged into Hearthstone on my phone for the first time in forever to test this.

Comment: Great idea. There are a couple categories of AoE you might not have thought about. 1. All characters. (Hellfire) 2. All minions (Wild Pyromancer). And of course there are cards which hit all except certain tpyes, or only hit certain types of minions (Scarlet Purifier vs. Dragonfire Potion). Source: https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Area_of_effect